# Very Simple D3: How to Draw an Arc?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

It would be nice to learn D3.  After reading many examples, I think I understand it.  My first project is to make a color wheel, without transitions for simplicity.  But it appears even that is not simple enough for my first project!  For project zero, I am trying to get something to show on the screen.  Hopefully something I wrote (and dear read has fixed), and not an example.

What did I do wrong?  http://jsfiddle.net/aGdMX/1/

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(40)
    .outerRadius(100)
    .startAngle(0)
    .endAngle(1)
    ;

var chart = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("class", "chart")
    .attr("width", 420)
    .attr("height", 420).append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(200,200)")
    ;

chart.selectAll("path")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i){
        return d3.rgb("black");
    })
    .attr("d", arc)
    ;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your example here doesn't have any data defined. If you just want to draw the svg statically, skip the selectAll() and data() bindings:

```
chart
    .append("svg:path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i){
        return d3.rgb("black");
    })
    .attr("d", arc)
    ;
```

Or define some data and use that to drive the drawing:

http://jsfiddle.net/findango/aGdMX/2/

(plus `.attr("fill"`...  should be `.style("fill"`...)

Comment: Thank you for the working jsfiddle link.  I am disappointed I can make more than one mistake on such a simple example.