# Generate a series of points that describe an arc in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to generate a semi-circle of points using JS, but don't know the math to accomplish this. What formula would I use? The use of the formula I can manage.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math formulas, not programing.

Comment: Fair enough, but it is concise and the answer is exactly what someone looking for this type of thing would want, so I don't think it should be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic formula to find the x/y coordinates of a point on a circle is:

X = circleX + ( circleRadius * cosine( angle ) )

Y = circleY + ( circleRadius * sine( angle ) )

Where circleX and circleY are the x/y coordinates of the center of your circle

```js
//Math functions use radians so we will need to convert degrees to radians
var radPerDeg = Math.PI/180;

function genPoint(centerX,centerY,degree,radius){
    var x = centerX + ( radius * Math.cos(degree*radPerDeg) );
    var y = centerY + ( radius * Math.sin(degree*radPerDeg) );

    var p = document.createElement("div");
    p.style.left = x+"px";
    p.style.top = y+"px";    
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}

for(var i=0; i<=180; i+=10){
   genPoint(200,100,i,50);
}
```

```css
div {
   border-radius:5px;
   width:5px;
   height:5px;
   background:#000;
   position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using HTML5 canvas or SVG. 
http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/
here you can find a list of attributes using svg https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute

But your question was using javascript.
For do that with javascript I think the best way is through D3.js http://d3js.org/
This is the good site to start d3 https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes

And here you have your solution [Very Simple D3: How to Draw an Arc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103752/very-simple-d3-how-to-draw-an-arc)