# Finding the x and y co-ordinates on circle in d3 pie chart

Tags: d3.js

I need to display a tooltip outside the d3 pie chart outer edge. For that I need to find the x and y co-ordinates on the outer edge.

I was able to bring the tooltip based on the mouse location using d3.event.pageX and d3.event.pageY. But I want to place the tool tip on the center of the outer arc of the pie slice.

Any pointers on how to find the co-ordinates for it will be helpful

Comment: do you have a JSFiddle ?

Comment: You can use the implementation of [`arc.centroid()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#arc_centroid) as a starting point. The only difference in your case is that you would take the outer radius and not the middle between inner and outer radius.

Answer (score 0):

From D3.js [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#arc_centroid):

```
arcs.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return d.value; });
```

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103752/very-simple-d3-how-to-draw-an-arc) for a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mA3V7/1/)